# Using malloc() properly

Tags: c, malloc

I use malloc while i was writing code in C, but i am getting

> [Warning] conflicting types for built-in function 'malloc'

this warning when i compile.

and this is the code that i use :

```
starttimer(AorB,increment)
int AorB;  /* A or B is trying to stop timer */
float increment;
{

 struct event *q;
 struct event *evptr;
 char *malloc();

 if (TRACE>2)
    printf("          START TIMER: starting timer at %f\n",time);
 /* be nice: check to see if timer is already started, if so, then  warn */
/* for (q=evlist; q!=NULL && q->next!=NULL; q = q->next)  */
   for (q=evlist; q!=NULL ; q = q->next)  
    if ( (q->evtype==TIMER_INTERRUPT  && q->eventity==AorB) ) { 
      printf("Warning: attempt to start a timer that is already started\n");
      return;
      }

/* create future event for when timer goes off */
   evptr = (struct event *)malloc(sizeof(struct event));
   evptr->evtime =  time + increment;
   evptr->evtype =  TIMER_INTERRUPT;
   evptr->eventity = AorB;
   insertevent(evptr);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `char *malloc();` - what are you doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`, and remove your bogus declaration: `char *malloc();`

Also, you need to **find a newer C reference!**  The K&R function declaration syntax has been obsolete for a very long time.

Consider changing:

```
starttimer(AorB,increment)
int AorB;  /* A or B is trying to stop timer */
float increment;
{
```

to the (sane-looking) ANSI C standard:

```
int starttimer(int AorB, float increment) {
```

Comment: i've already add #include <stdlib.h> but it still gives me same error

Comment: Remove the `char *malloc()`

Comment: To put a finer point on it: K&R function declarations have been obsolete since the release of the ANSI C standard in 1989. **This was about 25 years ago.** It's frankly amazing that compilers still tolerate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *malloc();
```

I am not sure why you redeclare the library function `malloc`. Any how here is the declaration of `malloc`

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Please include `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: The asker does not redefine `malloc()`, just declare it with a wrong type.

Comment: @leeduhem thanks for spotting that. updated the answer:)